# Akka ActorSystem creation issue

Tags: java, scala, akka

We are using Akka 2.0 RC1 and get an exception on ActorSystem creation with message: `akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider` and stack trace as follows:

```
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:279)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:520)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:450)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:385)
akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.getClassFor(DynamicAccess.scala:94)
akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:102)
akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:439)
akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:41)
akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:51)
kozo.excel.impl.ConnectClient.<init>(ConnectClient.scala:26)
```

The exception occurs on this line:

```
system = ActorSystem("FunctionClient")
```

Any thoughts or ideas? We did confirm that LocalActorRefProvider was in classpath.

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?  Can you show the application.conf?

Comment: No application.conf for this process.

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you did put the actual exception message in your question, but I will go on a limb here and assume this is this error message as [illustrated in this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/akka-user/browse_thread/thread/a0a69e3aff587183?hide_quotes=no):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: interface akka.actor.ActorRefProvider is
not assignable from class akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider
```

> It runs fine for me too when I run it under the console through sbt the way you describe. However, if I run it using:

scala -classpath

> and import and execute, I do get the error I mentioned.

Cause:

> Akka uses the context class loader from the thread that created the `ActorSystem`, and since every line is on it's own loader, you'll have a problem if you don't use that.

Suggestion:

> Each line in the repl runs in a separate thread.
>   If you add the `-Yrepl-sync` option it should work fine

Comment: I use exception's getStackTraceString method to extract the stacktrace and that's included above. Also the getMessage seems close but doesn't match to yours. We are tying to fix the logging on the application so that i don't have to use getStackTraceString etc tricks. Where do i pass the -Yrepl -sync option ?

Comment: @Roy: To your scala (repl) session, or to your sbt session: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615318/how-to-make-sbt-console-use-yrepl-sync